# Visual studio 2017 when writing template literals, pressing carriage return puts cursor on start of string

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, ide, template-literals

I'm experiencing this annoying behaviour in Visual Studio 2017, while writing a `template literal` string:

```
var foo = `
    a
    b <- here for example
    c
    `;
```

if inside the string i press `carriage return` on any line, visual studio puts the cursor just before the starting backtick `, forcing me to use keyboard arrows to return where i was typing.
Any clue?

Comment: are you trying to insert newline between the characters?

Comment: Yes, too. But not only